# Where to start voice recognition development?

Tags: javascript, speech-recognition, voice-recognition

With the increase in voice recognition apps etc., I am also becoming interested in voice recognition development. However, I am not sure where to start.
Is there any possibilities using web based technology such as JavaScript on computers?
I have also started looking into Android development, so if it is difficult to start with on desktop computers, then I can also consider Android development of voice recognition apps if it is easier to get into. For now, I am more interested in learning than actually releasing anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to read up on [Phonetic algrothims](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonetic_algorithm) and [audio encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_codec) as a starter. Everything else you can start later, after you have an overview.

Comment: Thank you, I will check them out. I would upvote your comment if I could.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do with JavaScript is to use the Web Speech API. This allows you to quickly do voice recognition as well as speech synthesis.

Simplest example of Speech Synthesis:

```
var utterance = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance('Hello World');
window.speechSynthesis.speak(utterance);
```

Simplest example of Voice Recognition:

```
var recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
recognition.onresult = function(event) {
    console.log(event);
}
recognition.start();
```